# How to disable a form element based on the other component radio button option

Tags: angular

I have two component (parent and child component) , in parent component there is radio button options create, update, delete. If i select create option , student id element in the child component should get disabled. And on clicking the create radio button option a backend API call should be triggered to get the student id and populate the student id value in the child component student id element.

Can you please help on this.

Thanks

Parent Component

```
<mat-card class="student-registration-card" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="32px">
  <mat-card fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch">
      <mat-card-content>         
        <div class="student-registration-container">
          <form class="student-reg-container" [formGroup]="options">
            <div>
              <label> Action: </label>
              <mat-radio-group formControlName="floatLabel">
                <mat-radio-button (click)="create()" value="create">Create</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button (click)="update()" value="update">Update</mat-radio-button>
                <mat-radio-button (click)="delete()" value="delete">Delete</mat-radio-button>
              </mat-radio-group>
            </div>           
          </form>
        </div>      
      </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card-content *ngFor="let _ of [1]" fxLayout="column" fxLayout.lt-sm="column" fxLayoutGap="32px">
      <app-basic-details fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch" [action]="action"></app-basic-details>
      <app-address-details fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch"></app-address-details>
      <app-guardian-details fxFlex="0 1 calc(33.3% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-md="0 1 calc(50% - 32px)" fxFlex.lt-sm="100%" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly stretch"></app-guardian-details>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Child Component

```
<mat-card fxFlex="1000px" fxFlex.xs="100%">
        <!-- Title of an Card -->
        <mat-card-title>
            Student Basic Details
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
            <form>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field class="demo-full-width">
                                <input matInput placeholder="Student Id">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field>
                                <mat-label>Standard</mat-label>
                                <mat-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="standard">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let standard of standards" [value]="standard.value">
                                        {{standard.viewValue}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>

                    </tr>                    
                </table>
            </form>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're not using a formControl for your childElement, therefore, you need to pass a value as an input to your childComponent. That value can either be a boolean, set to true if you want to disable the child element, null otherwise, or it can be the value of your radioGroup, in which case the business logic would have to be in the child component... the former is easier....

Therefore, in your parent, have a property disableStudentId: boolean, then, after creating your FormGroup...

```
this.options.floatLabel.valueChanges.subscribe(
    val => this.disableStudentId = val === 'create' ? true : null
);
```

pass this as an input to your child component.... then in your child component html...

```
<input matInput placeholder="Student Id" [disabled]="disableStudentId">
```